# How can I use xsl:import with a variable in the path name?

Tags: xslt

Essentially I want do this in XSL:

```
<xsl:include href="_domains/{$domain}/templates/header.xsl" />
```

But I can't seem to use a variable ($domain) in the include.  Any suggestions on a work around?

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for an XSLT 2.0 - only possible (but limited) solution and another alternative, non-XSLT solution.

Answer (score 6):

`xsl:import` and `xsl:include` are resolved at compile time, and do not support runtime expansion.

Except, if you are using XSLT 2.0, you can use [conditional inclusion](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#conditional-inclusion) with `use-when`, if you have an expression that can be evaluated in a static context.

Comment: +1 Correct answer. Even in XSLT 2.0 the stylesheet module URI is not "dynamic". **It can be a relative URI**, of course...

Answer (score 3):

With the addition of [static parameters](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#dt-static-parameter), it is now possible to conditionally include in XSLT 3.0. Static parameters can be used in the `use-when` attribute of the `xsl:include`.

Now we can declare parameters with default values of `false()` and then override the ones we need at run time...

```
<xsl:param name="someparam" as="xs:boolean" select="false()" 
  static="yes" required="no"/>  
<xsl:include href="include_me.xsl" use-when="$someparam"/>
```

Here is a full working example tested with [Saxon-HE](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/) v9.7 (also tested with Saxon-PE 9.5).

**XML Input** (test.xml)

```
<doc>
    <foo/>
</doc>
```

**Main XSLT 3.0** (test_main.xsl)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  
  <xsl:param name="inc1" as="xs:boolean" select="false()" 
    static="yes" required="no"/>
  <xsl:param name="inc2" as="xs:boolean" select="false()" 
    static="yes" required="no"/>
  
  <xsl:include href="test_inc1.xsl" use-when="$inc1"/>
  <xsl:include href="test_inc2.xsl" use-when="$inc2"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**First possible included XSLT 3.0** (test_inc1.xsl)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:template match="foo">
    <xsl:copy>INCLUDE FILE 1!!!</xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Second possible included XSLT 3.0** (test_inc2.xsl)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:template match="foo">
    <xsl:copy>INCLUDE FILE 2!!!</xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Command line** (setting `inc2` to true)

```
java -cp "saxon9he.jar" net.sf.saxon.Transform -s:"test.xml" -xsl:"test_main.xsl" inc2="true"
```

**Output**

```
<doc>
   <foo>INCLUDE FILE 2!!!</foo>
</doc>
```

---

Here's another example, using the above files (except main.xsl), that is more like the original question where part of the path is a variable. Note the `_href` which is a [shadow attribute](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#shadow-attributes).

**Main XSLT 3.0**

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:param name="inc_number" as="xs:string" select="'1'" static="yes" required="no"/>

    <xsl:include _href="test_inc{$inc_number}.xsl"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 2):

As explained by @lavinio, in XSLT 2.0 the [**`use-when`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/2007/REC-xslt20-20070123/#conditional-inclusion) attribute may be used to allow a certain degree of "compile-time" inclusion of an xslt instruction, however this is only limited to testing conditions that can can be determined from values in the static context and from these dynamic context values: current date and time, and implicit time zone.

**Another approach is** to load the XSLT stylesheet (as an XML document) at runtime and before initiating the transformation to dynamically set the `href` attribute of any desired `<xsl:include>` and/or `<xsl:import>` instructions.

This technique is used by the XPath Visualizer to dynamically change the XSLT stylesheet that then evaluates the user-specified XPath expression and formats the XML document with all selected and visible nodes -- highlighted.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to load an XML file and transform it by a set of rules (this file could even be a simple XSLT variant).

```
<xsl:param name="domain">_default</xsl:param>

<xsl:variable name="header-template"
   select="document( concat('_domains/', $domain, '/templates/header.xml' ) )" />

<xsl:template name="header">
  <xsl:apply-templates mode="transform" select="$header-template"/>
</xsl:template>
```